# optimizing sql selects on mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I've been handed the thankless task of cleaning up a custom PHP app built with the absence of any MVC or proper design patterns and am currently experiencing a massive performance hit on a view due to queries per row.

I'd like some general guideline on where to start optimizing and where my time would most benefit the loading issues.

Here is how it's working as handed to me. For example, each row is operating these functions:

```
$purchased = report::purchased_products_total($customer['No'],$from, $to);
$returned = report::returned_products_total($customer['No'],$from, $to);
$cust_inv = $purchased-$returned;
$on_hand_total = report::get_onhand_qty_total($customer['No'],$from, $to);
$log_sale_qty = report::get_logged_sale_qty($customer['No'],$from, $to);
$expected = $cust_inv-$log_sale_qty;
$salesman = report::get_salesman_by_code($customer['Salesperson_Code']);
$salesman_name = str_replace("'","",$salesman->Name);
$phone = str_replace("/","-",$customer['Phone_No']);
$name = str_replace("'","",$customer['Name']);
```

Example of his sql, here is the purchased_products_total function:

```
public static function purchased_products_total($no,$from=NULL,$to=NULL,$item=FALSE){
  global $db;   
  $data= $db->QuerySingleValue("SELECT sum(a.Quantity) FROM ".INVOICE_LINES." as a
  WHERE a.Type='Item'
  AND No NOT LIKE 'ZB%' AND No NOT LIKE 'ZE%' AND No NOT LIKE 'ZN%'
  AND No NOT LIKE 'ZP%'AND No NOT LIKE 'ZR%'AND No NOT LIKE 'ZZ%'
  AND a.Sell_To_customer_No='$no'
  AND a.Stock_No!='NULL'
  AND Document_Posting_Date>='$from' 
  AND Document_Posting_Date<='$to'

  "
 );

 return $data;  
 }
```

The Invoice Lines table is MyISAM.

I can post more of the functions if needed. I ran a performance test and mysql_query is being run about 3,500 times and is taking almost 3 min to operate.

Comment: First all you sholud use  REGEXP instead of LIKE in the my sqlquery `NOT REGEXP '^(ZB|ZE|ZN|...){1}'`

Comment: @ob_start thanks!! Is this something I should do across the board?

Comment: and all of the fields in the `WHERE` and `SELECT` part should be have indexes,too (Test sql with EXPLAIN to see wich keys you need). **across the board** i think where its needed and its makes the code celaner

Comment: @ob_start according to this article REGEXP performance in comparison to like is "less than fantastic". Thoughts?  https://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/

Comment: good point,  there are lots of thing that can change mysql preformance (right indexes,keys / table type / regex,like complexity and so on), was just a try (only comment no answer ;))

Comment: @ob_start no worries at all this discourse could benefit a lot of people! It's a rats nest I've been handed, hopefully I can suss out a checklist from this post

Comment: but you can try to move the LIKES down, after the other conditions.try and benchmark ;)

Comment: here a nice link about `EXPLAIN` and sql http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652&seqNum=2

Answer (score 0):

Be sure all your query fields are indexed. You can also use [SUBSTRING(No, 2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) [IN('ZB', 'ZE', 'ZN', ...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to test for inclusion of the first two characters, rather than the long string of AND ... NOT LIKE ...

If this pattern is very common, you could even break out the first two characters into a separate column, or make a "covering index" that is only two characters long.

In general, do what you can to get rid of LIKE to speed things up!